# Is it possible to send SSH instructions via a Kivy Android app?

Tags: android, python, ssh, raspberry-pi, kivy

My goal here is to have a simple Kivy app. When a button on-screen is pressed on an Android phone, it runs a command via SSH on my Raspberry Pi on the same network. Would I be capable of doing this on Android? I know I could get it to work on an actual Ubuntu environment with Kivy, but not entirely sure if Android is capable of that.